# pgAdmin won't run standalone

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I'm running Debian 9 with separate root e home partitions, installed postgreSQL and pgAdmin4 following these steps:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ stretch-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'

sudo apt-get install wget ca-certificates

wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.6 pgadmin4
```

From: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt

I had it installed previously, but while trying to update psycopg2 I accidentally uninstalled pgAdmin4. After the re-installation I was only able to run from the terminal, so decided to do a purge and start from scratch, now pgAdmin4 won't open as a standalone application, only opens on a browser.

If anyone has an idea how to fix it, I'd appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected behavior, Now onwards pgAdmin4 will launch application using the default browser from the user system.

Ref: https://redmine.postgresql.org/issues/3086

Comment: The link that you have referred to is pretty useless as it requires the reader to register for the PostgreSQL issue system. Perhaps you could copy and paste relevant information from this post so that the rest of us can see it?